# jQuery Validation plugin custom error message with icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I created an email validation script using the jQuery validation plugin. I want to show the error message with an error icon image just like in the picture. How can I achieve that?

[image: See the picture here]

[image: Here's the icon error image]

```js
$("#form-1").validate();
```

```html
<section class="right-section">
  <img class="logo" src="images/logo.svg" alt="Base Apparel Logo">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1 class="heading-1">
        <span class="sc-1">WE'RE</span><br> 
        COMING<br>
        SOON
      </h1>
      <p class="para-1">Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store. Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our launch deals.</p>
      <form id="form-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Email Address">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-deafult" style="float: right;" type="submit">
          <img src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="button-image-arrow" />
        </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img class="desktop-img" src="images/hero-desktop.jpg" alt="Model-pic">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin and the jQuery Validation Engine are two different plugins.  Please be more careful when tagging.  Edited.

Comment: You've made absolutely no attempt to configure the plugin with anything to achieve your goal.  An attempt is expected before asking for help.   We're not a free code-writing service.